# What happened to the engines on takeoff here (loud popping sound then silence)

Tags: boeing-737, accident-investigation, incidents, ryanair

What is the cause of the sound shortly after rotation in [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uJfs5YRK-F0)?

And does anyone know what flight this was and what happened? (i.e. incident report) as I can't find any news about a fatal RyanAir incident, but I can't see how they would have recovered at that altitude

If the video is fake, i.e. the audio is from another flight, then which flight is the audio from?

Comment: Ryanair have never had a fatal accident, which is why you can't find anything.

Comment: @GdD Engine failures are also investigated.

Comment: If the engines had both failed at that altitude the airplane would not have been able to make it back to the airport. Plus, when the engines die the airplane continues to climb. It's obviously fake.

Comment: The poster says that the video is fake, and that does not mean that the audio is real.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for an explanation of a fake video. That's an unanswerable and unproductive distraction.

Comment: @RalphJ distraction from what exactly? I'm asking where the audio is from. That is certainly not unanswerable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The audio sounds very much like a [compressor stall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressor_stall), followed by the engine rolling back, likely due to the pilot reducing power.

Compressor stalls can occur for a wide variety of reasons. Damage from a bird strike or other [FOD](https://skybrary.aero/articles/foreign-object-debris-fod) ingestion, excessive turbulence in the intake air, malfunctioning [variable stator vanes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/what-are-variable-stator-vanes)... the list goes on.

Even though the video is fake (as admitted by the uploader), there's no reason to assume that the audio came from a fatal crash. Planes do occasionally lose engines during takeoff, and it's rarely fatal, since commercial planes have to be able to fly with one engine out.

Unfortunately, because compressor stalls have such a wide variety of causes, without more information, it isn't possible to tell where the original audio came from.